# AngularJS mocking $logProvider in config block

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-runner

Is there a way to inject providers when writing unit tests using Karma(Testacular) and Jasmine in angular?

Our team decided recently to use angularjs $log to write debugging details to the console. This way we can leverage the ability to disable the logging via the `$logProvider.debugEnabled()` method.

```
angular.module("App", ["prismLogin", "ui.bootstrap"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$logProvider", 
     function ($routeProvider, $logProvider) {
         $routeProvider
         //routes here edited for brevity

         //This is the offending line, it breaks several pre-existing tests
         $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
     }]);
```

However after adding the `$logProvider.debugEnabled(true);` line several of our tests no longer execute successfully, failing with the following message:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'debugEnabled' from App
```

So my question again, is it possible to mock the `$logProvider`? Or should I provide my own configuration block for the test harness?

I attempted searching for a way to mock the app module with no luck. It seems to me that using the concrete app module instead of a mock is very brittle. I would like to avoid reworking tests associated with the app module every time a change is made in the app or run configuration blocks.

The tests that are failing are units of code with no relation to the `$logProvider`? I feel as if I a missing something here and making things much harder than they should be. How should one go about writing tests that are flexible and are not affected by other side effects introduced in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a [know issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2343) with angular-mocks.

Until the issue is addressed , I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following method to the `angular.mock.$LogProvider` definition in angular-mocks.js at line 295.

```
this.debugEnabled = function(flag) {
   return this;
};
```

Comment: Jonathan - do you mean "return true"?